# Rotating camera view on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've read few questions here on stack and I'm in a dead-end. I want to have device (iPhone/iPad) camera as a background, to one of my `ViewControllers`. I'm using `Storyboard` and `UINavigationsViewController`, so I'm modyfing a child `ViewController`. As far as I read, this means that I cannot force this "child" to start in specific orientation (first problem).
Secondly, I decided to go with `UIImagePickerController`, but as I got it right - you cannot rotate this component, right?

So basically my question is where to go from here, to achieve camera view on background no matter what device orientation? It surely can be done, because Vuforia i.e. has it (and they are using UIImagePickerController with EAGLView).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that task:

1) You can use `Eaglview` to render the frames of camera device in background.
2) You can use `caeagllayer` to do the same.

To draw on that layer you have to use `drawableproperties` and `CaTransformationMatrix`